# Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:generateSafeArgsDebug' (type 'ArgumentsGenerationTask'). After upgrading gradle to 7.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:generateSafeArgsDebug' (type 'ArgumentsGenerationTask').

- Type 'ArgumentsGenerationTask' property 'applicationId' is missing an input or output annotation.

Comment: This doesn't look like a problem with your code, but with the Navigation Safe Args plugin. Can you [file an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409828) with a sample project that reproduces your issue? That will make sure the correct people can fix the issue.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

I just came across this issue too when upgrading to Gradle 7. Managed to fix it by switching my old navigation safe args plugin to the AndroidX version - Not sure how I missed that during my AndroidX refactor

```
// From
classpath("android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0")

// To
classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.1")
```

Comment: I had missed it as well. Thanks.

Comment: but your question did not help as well

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned by @mononz, the issue was caused by upgrading Android Gradle Plugin to version `7.0.0` but @Androiderson's comment helped fix the issue as I was already using the AndroidX version. I updated the safe args plugin to version `2.3.5`. [Navigation Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation)

Answer (score 7):

```
    To solve the error just go to the project level gradle file and change your navigation plugin to the new AndroidX version plugin, as shown below.
    
classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0"  //old plugin.

     //to the new plugin
     
def nav_version = "2.3.5"
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-

plugin:$nav_version"
```